# Question about writing out a trapezoidal integration method

Tags: python, math

Hi I am currently writing a Python program that divide `1` to `0` to `n` pieces, and integrate it base on number of pieces, each trapezoid will have `(1-0)/n` as their equal width.

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import sqrt,sin,arange

def f(x):
    return (sin(sqrt(100*x))**2)

def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s += f(a)/2.0

    for i in range(1, n):
        s += f(a + i*h)

    s += f(b)/2.0
    return s * h

print(trapezoidal(f(x), 5, 10, 100))
```

Do you guys think this code could work ?Also, how do you add a sequence or a loop that it calculate area for `1,2,4,8,16` until `2^10`?

Comment: Answer: No it can't work because it's not indented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

incorrect indentation. try this

```
import numpy as np

 def f(x):
     return (np.sin(np.sqrt(100*x))**2)



def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s += f(a)/2.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        s += f(a + i*h)
        s += f(b)/2.0
    return s * h

print( trapezoidal(f(x), 5, 10, 100))
```